# Best practice control client socket thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets

So, I have a following problem:
I have a thread for client socket(for example **SingleSocketThread**). I create and start this thread if it is not alive and not created or socket is not connected else I do interrupt this thread and re-create new thread and start it and connect to socket server in runnable block. But when opened another activity or application enter to background mode(for example user press home button) I need disconnect socket but need keep SingleSocketThread and when return application to foreground I need connect socket to socket server again.

Anybody know how to right solve this problem? Anybody have a best way control thread and effective use created thread to using socket in another thread.

Comment: To get the most help from the SO community, you need to post what you have tried so far to solve this problem. It is easier to answer questions that have attached code that illustrates the problem you have.

Comment: I fully explain my problem here not need pass code, here simple need answer how to manage thread to client socket. Problem any time need disconnect socket and any time need re connect socket but this time don't stop thread and thread need always keep is alive.

Comment: If you disconnect then why do you want to keep your thread?

Comment: `I fully explain my problem here`. I doubt that. `not need pass code`. I doubt that. `need answer how to manage thread to client socket.`. Better kill it. Start a new when needed.

Comment: There are a lot of unexplained assumptions here. For example, why do you think you need to keep the thread alive after disconnecting?

Comment: **why do you think you need to keep the thread alive after disconnecting** because create thread and start its is not cheap.